# Silverlight AutoComplete TextBox Ignore special characters

Tags: c#, vb.net, silverlight, xaml

I have an autocomplete box doing a search in my database. The sql command removes special characters but the textbox does not display the results because the returned results contain those special ones.

For example if i type in 1234 the sql server will return 1234 and 123-4 but the autocomplete box will only show 1234. Is there a way where i can get both to display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the ItemFilter property on the Autocomplex box to use your own custom filtering that would include the special characters. Something like:

```
//custom logic: how to autocomplete 
this.ItemFilter = (prefix, item) =>
{
   return item.ToString().Replace("-","").Contains(prefix);
};
```

Obviously you'd need to add more to it, but that should get you started.

**EDIT**: Thinking more about this after responding to comments, if your SQL server is already doing the filtering you want, then just set the AutoCompleteFilterMode to None. That should do the trick. :)

Comment: Wouldn't it cost less in memory/cpu time to just store a duplicate of the entire thing with dashes stripped out?

Comment: I don't think that code is going to cost a lot of memory/cpu. :) You'd have to have thousands of items which at that point this code is the least of your issues.

Comment: but isn't this ToString.Replace.Contains() being performed on every item at every new character added? Not exactly the most efficient. It's a mobile device -- if you could instead just use Contains()...

Comment: That is the problem. The string "abc" doesn't *contain" "ab-c". His SQL code is returning both "abc" and "ab-c" for the prefix "abc" if I understand the question correctly. Also since his autocomplete is using SQL to prefilter the results it should only be a limited number of items coming back.

Comment: Just did an edit, I think it might make it more efficient. :)